# Equivalent Recurrence Relations

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

Playing around with sequences, I observed the following:

> Take $a_1=b_1=1$ and $a_2=b_2=k$ for fixed $k$ with $1<k<2$.
>
> Prove that if $a_{n+2}=\frac{a_{n+1}^2-1}{a_n}$ and $b_{n+2}=kb_{n+1}-b_n$,
>
> then $a_n=b_n, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}.$

This can be shown by guessing $a_n=\frac{2}{4-k^2}\sin[\cos^{-1}(\frac{k}{2})n]$ and using the formula $\sin(\alpha+x)\sin(\alpha-x)=\sin^2(\alpha)-\sin^2(x)$ to derive the recurrence, and guessing $b_n=r^n$ and solving for the coefficients of the linearly independent solutions, then comparing the closed forms of $a_n$ and $b_n$.

Can anyone however come up with a non-"Deus Ex Machina" proof, say by induction?

Comment: How the hell did you guess *that* for $a_n$ 

Comment: Intuition, based off the trig formula above

Comment: difference of terms ??

Comment: Okay so the recurrence relation for $b_n$ is linear and there is a basically complete theory on it, so if you just find a closed form for $b_n$ and see if it satisfies the relation that $a_n$ does then you are already done with your proof. Seems easy enough without having to have the deus ex machina intuition for $a_n$

Comment: Yes but that also feels like a cop out. I guess I'm looking for a non constructive proof.

Comment: I can probably figure a few terms algebraically and solve this, why is it interesting ?

Comment: The recurrence relation for $a_n$ was involved in a BMO problem

Comment: does induction count as non-constructive I need to iron out a few details but can already show $a_3=b_3$ I'm just not great generally.

Comment: @gfppoy Okay so according to my "there is no cop out in math, what works works" philosophy, you can proceed like this: It is easy to prove that $$b_n=-\frac{2^{-n}
   \left(\left(k-\sqrt{k^2-4}\right)^n-\left(\sqrt{k^2-4}+k\right)^n\right)}{\sqrt{k^
   2-4}}$$ So $$b_{n+2}-\frac{b_{n+1}^2-1}{b_n}=\frac{\sqrt{k^2-4} 2^{-n} \left(\left(k-\sqrt{k^2-4}\right)^n
   \left(\sqrt{k^2-4}+k\right)^n-4^n\right)}{\left(k-\sqrt{k^2-4}\right)^n-\left(\sqrt{k^2-4}+k\right)^n}=0$$ because the right term in brackets in the numerator is $0$

Comment: Partial induction: 

$$a_n=b_n\land a_{n+1}=b_{n+1}$$

Implies by substitution, and factoring the numerator algebraically that $$(k-1)(k+1)=k(k)-1$$ so $n=1$ implies $$a_3=b_3$$  more  generally there's a difference of squares or you can use, or multiply by equal $a_n,b_n$ I'm broke after that. in my thought of induction you can factor out a $k-1$ because $kb_{n+1}+b_n=(k-1)b_{n+1}+(b_{n+1}-b_n)$ and the difference of squares originally has that as a factor.

Comment: By the way here is a related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2467605/show-an-identity-from-friezes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rewriting the relation about $a_n$, we get for $n\geq 2$
$$1=a^2_{n+1}-a_na_{n+2}=a^2_{n}-a_{n-1}a_{n+1} $$
Hence
$$a_{n+1}\left(a_{n+1}+a_{n-1}\right)=a_n\left(a_{n}+a_{n+2}\right)\Leftrightarrow \\
\frac{a_n+a_{n+2}}{a_{n+1}}=\frac{a_{n+1}+a_{n-1}}{a_{n}} $$
Since this is true for all $n\geq 2$, we can substitute $n=2$ in the RHS. We calculate $a_3=k^2-1$. So
$$\frac{a_n+a_{n+2}}{a_{n+1}}=\frac{a_3+a_1}{a_2}=\frac{k^2-1+1}{k}=k \Leftrightarrow \\
a_{n+2}=ka_{n+1}-a_n $$
It can be manually checked the last relation holds for $n=1$ as well. So $a_n=b_n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. For a complete proof, we need to justify the division by $a_n$, that is, we need to show $a_n\ne 0$.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.

Comment: @gfppoy Note that if $k=\sqrt{2}$, then $a_4=0$, so it's not clear what $a_6$ is. On the other hand, $b_n$'s are defined. So perhaps, $a_n\ne 0$ should be given explicitly as a hypothesis.